# Paypal APIs - Update recurring payment profile

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

Our system is using **Paypal Classic Apis** for recurring payment feature.
I can **create** new profiles and **update** profiles that have just created.

But when I try to **update profiles that have been started** (start date is older than today), the API throws this error:

```
Ack : Failure
[ShortMessage] => Cannot update after subscription started
[LongMessage] => Cannot update after subscription started
[ErrorCode] => 7292
[SeverityCode] => Error
[ErrorParameters] => NULL
```

I just want to change Amount (per billing cycle) and Start Date, the other parameters keep the same.

As I know, *Brain Tree* and *Authorize.net* allow user to update fields of subscriptions whenever merchant wants. They don't care if a subscription was started or not. Am I wrong?

Base on the above response from Paypal Apis, when I need to update some specific information for a started recurring payment profile, I have to created a new profile that has the same information with the old one except some fields that I need to change. This is too complicated.

Also, the error code 7292 is not mentioned in Paypal Apis error codes: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/#id09C3G0B0JK3

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you update you can't set a new start date because the profile has already started.  You can't have another start date...that date has already come and gone.

Just leave startdate out of your Update request and the problem should go away.

Comment: Your means is cannot set new start date when profile has already started. So if I want to change start date, user should be re-enter new credit card? Because no way to create new profile without credit card info. Is that right or is there another way to create new profile from old profile and no need to re-fill credit card?

Comment: You'll need to use CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile again if you're trying to create a new profile.  You can't just convert an old one into a new one.  You could update an existing one, though, and change pretty much everything except for the start date...since it's already started.